# How to solve numerically a double integral that converges slowly?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, integral-equations

I'm having trouble trying to numerically solve the following double integral in Mathematica, which I know, a priori, has a solution for values of $mh \in[0.4,2.0]$ and $tmer = 0.017$, $tmel = 0.044$.

```
tmer = 0.017; tmel = 0.044;
    IDtest[mh_] := 
 1/(8*Pi^3)*
  NIntegrate[(mh*tmer^(1/
      2)*(tmer^(1/2)*Sqrt[w^2 - 1]*
         Sqrt[(u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel] + 
        1/2*(mh^2 - tmer - tmel) + (w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - 
        u*w*mh*tmer^(1/2)))*
    Exp[u*mh]/((Exp[u*mh] - 1)*(Exp[w*tmer^(1/2)] + 
       1)*(Exp[u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2)] + 1)), {u, 1, +\[Infinity]}, {w, 
    1, +\[Infinity]}]
```

If you run, for instance, `ID[0.4]` you'll see that the numerical integration is converging too slowly, due to the `Exp[u*mh]` term in the numerator. Furthemore, it returns a complex number, thanks to `Sqrt[(u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel]`. However, I want to impose that `(u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 >= tmel`. If done correctly, I would expect `ID[0.4]` to output `0.000025385` or close to it. Is there a way to deal with the mentioned slow convergence and impose the above condition?

**EDIT:** Firstly, I want to thank everyone for the detailed answers given below and for the time you spent tackling this problem. I'm very grateful!
Secondly, I think it would be not only pedagogically relevant, but also interesting to give a bit of a background which culminated in this god-forsaken integral. Thus, to anyone interested, this was my attempt on trying to solve the following integral:

```
$$
I_D=2{\displaystyle \int} \, {\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^3} d \Pi_i \, (2\pi
)^4\delta^4(p_H-p_L-p_R)  |{\cal M}({e_L}^c e_R  \leftrightarrow h^*)|^2
f_{L}^0f_{R}^0(1+f_{H}^0).$$
```

which is a reaction density that enters the Boltzmann equations that describe the evolution of right-handed and left-handed electrons. In particular, this integral amounts for the contributions of Higgs bosons decays into right-handed and left-handed electrons. This integral has been solved in a particular paper where the authors reduced it to one dimension:

```
$$
I_D = \frac{m_H T^3h_e^2\gamma^2}{\pi^3}\int_1^\infty d u \frac{e^{um_H/T}}
        {(e^{um_H/T}-1)^2}
\! \ln \left( \frac {\textstyle \cosh (\alpha_{e_L} u + \gamma \sqrt{u^2-1})}
               {\textstyle \cosh (\alpha_{e_L} u - \gamma \sqrt{u^2-1})}
% \right. \nonumber \\ & \t \left.
\frac {\textstyle \cosh (\alpha_{e_R} u + \gamma \sqrt{u^2-1})}
             {\textstyle \cosh (\alpha_{e_R} u - \gamma \sqrt{u^2-1})} \right).$$
```

where

```
$$
\alpha_{e_L}\equiv (m_H^2+m_{e_L}^2-m_{e_R}^2)/4m_HT$$
$$
\alpha_{e_R}\equiv (m_H^2+m_{e_R}^2-m_{e_L}^2)/4m_HT$$
$$
\gamma\equiv \lambda^{\frac{1}{2}}(m_H^2, m_{e_L}^2, m_{e_R}^2)/4m_HT$$
$$
\lambda(x,y,z)\equiv (x-y-z)^2-4yz$$
```

and `$f^0_i=(e^{\beta E_i}\pm 1)^{-1}$`, whether the particle species is a fermion(+) or a boson(-).
Unfortunately, they don't explain how they got to this result and I haven't managed to get there either. So my attempt was to analitically solve this integral and reduce it to two dimensions and finally solve it numerically using Mathematica (thus the ensuing question). This was my attempt:
[image]

Unfortunately, my results do not match the paper's results and I'm still to understand where I've gone wrong.
**PS:** for some reason stackexchange doesn't validate my edit if I don't indent my latex code... I apologize for that.

Comment: What values of $tmer$ and $tmel$ are you using?

Comment: Just edited my question to insert their values. Thank you very much for pointing that out, I had completely forgotten to mention them.

Comment: Let us look at the denominator of the integrand `((E^(0.130384 w) + 1) (E^(mh u) - 1) (E^(mh u - 0.130384 w) + 1))`. The mutipliers `(E^(0.130384 w) + 1) ` and `E^(mh u - 0.130384 w) + 1)` cancel as `w` tends to infinity. This causes the divergence  in `w` since the numerator has power growth in `w` (see  `mh*tmer^(1/2)*(tmer^(1/2)*Sqrt[w^2 - 1]*
       Sqrt[(u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel] + 
      1/2*(mh^2 - tmer - tmel) + (w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - 
      u*w*mh*tmer^(1/2)))*
  Exp[u*mh]/((Exp[u*mh] - 1)*(Exp[w*tmer^(1/2)] + 
       1)*(Exp[u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2)] + 1)) // TraditionalForm`).

Comment: Sorry, I was not right: `E^(0.130384 w) + 1)`  and `E^(mh u - 0.130384 w) + 1)` do not cancel .

Comment: No problem! I got confused about that at first, but thank you for clarifying!

Comment: How about: `IDtest[mh_] := 
 With[{tmer = .017 // Rationalize, tmel = .044 // Rationalize}, 
  NIntegrate[(mh*
      tmer^(1/2)*(tmer^(1/2)*Sqrt[w^2 - 1]*
         Sqrt[(u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel] + 
        1/2*(mh^2 - tmer - tmel) + (w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - 
        u*w*mh*tmer^(1/2)))*UnitStep[(u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel]*
    Exp[u*
       mh]/((Exp[u*mh] - 1)*(Exp[w*tmer^(1/2)] + 
         1)*(Exp[u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2)] + 1)), {u, 1, 
    10, +\[Infinity]}, {w, 1, 10, +\[Infinity]}, 
   Method -> "LocalAdaptive", PrecisionGoal -> 8]];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We cam map region of integration to the unit square by substitution `u->1/x,w->1/y` and use some option to reduce time of integration as follows

```
tmer = .017; tmel = .044;
IDtest[mh_] := 
 1/(8*Pi^3)*
  NIntegrate[
   UnitStep[(u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel] (mh*
       tmer^(1/2)*(tmer^(1/2)*Sqrt[w^2 - 1]*
          Sqrt[Sqrt[((u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel)^2]] + 
         1/2*(mh^2 - tmer - tmel) + (w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - 
         u*w*mh*tmer^(1/2)))*
     Exp[u*mh]/((Exp[u*mh] - 1)*(Exp[w*tmer^(1/2)] + 
            1)*(Exp[u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2)] + 1))/x^2/y^2 /. {u -> 1/x, 
     w -> 1/y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 5]
```

Result is real in every point on `{mh,0.4, 2}` and at `mh=0.4` is approximately same as it computed by @Akku14

```
IDtest[.4] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[]= {0.049577, 0.0234493}
```

Visualization

```
Plot[IDtest[mh], {nh, .4, 2}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Test from MichelE2

```
Table[mh->IDtest[mh],{mh,0.4,2.,0.1}]//AbsoluteTiming
{1.03552, {0.4 -> 0.0234493, 0.5 -> 0.0207405, 0.6 -> 0.0185858, 
  0.7 -> 0.0168389, 0.8 -> 0.0153775, 0.9 -> 0.014138, 1. -> 0.013071,
   1.1 -> 0.0121509, 1.2 -> 0.0113453, 1.3 -> 0.0106358, 
  1.4 -> 0.0100059, 1.5 -> 0.00944436, 1.6 -> 0.00893805, 
  1.7 -> 0.00848478, 1.8 -> 0.00807154, 1.9 -> 0.00769319, 
  2. -> 0.00734856}}
```

We can compare result with his original code

```
{2.63589, {0.4 -> 0.0234479 + 8.80489*10^-29 I, 0.5 -> 0.0207372, 
  0.6 -> 0.0185911, 0.7 -> 0.0168386, 0.8 -> 0.0153765, 
  0.9 -> 0.014137, 1. -> 0.0130732, 1.1 -> 0.012151, 1.2 -> 0.0113448,
   1.3 -> 0.0106348, 1.4 -> 0.0100052, 1.5 -> 0.00944348, 
  1.6 -> 0.00893923, 1.7 -> 0.00848393, 1.8 -> 0.00807048, 
  1.9 -> 0.00769287, 2. -> 0.00734608}}
```

Small discrepancies are due to option `PrecisionGoal -> 5` using in my code. In turn I am using this option since input parameters `tmer = .017; tmel = .044;` defined with low accuracy.

Comment: Really very good idea, beside the tricky transformation, to introduce `UnitStep` to force real part of integration. Why did you omit the part `NIntegrate[ (1-UnitStep[..])...,...]`?

Comment: I got it, didn't read the question  carefully

Answer (score 5):

It looks like using `Method -> "LocalAdaptive"` in `NIntegrate` solves the convergence problems, but you may want to perform some consistency checks on the results:

```
f[tmer_, tmel_, mh_] := 
 NIntegrate[(mh*
     tmer^(1/2)*(tmer^(1/2)*Sqrt[w^2 - 1]*
        Sqrt[(u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel] + 
       1/2*(mh^2 - tmer - tmel) + (w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - 
       u*w*mh*tmer^(1/2)))*
   Exp[u*mh]/((Exp[u*mh] - 1)*(Exp[w*tmer^(1/2)] + 
        1)*(Exp[u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2)] + 1)), {u, 1, +\[Infinity]}, {w, 
   1, +\[Infinity]}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]

ReImPlot[f[.017, .044, mh], {mh, .4, 2.}]
```

[image]

(Note the small imaginary part near the horizontal axis.)

Comment: It is nice solution (+1), but you are not using restriction  `(u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 >= tmel` .

Answer (score 4):

This works quite fast.

```
{tmer = .017 // Rationalize, tmel = .044 // Rationalize};

ii[u_, w_, mh_] = 
1/(8*Pi^3)*(mh*
  tmer^(1/2)*(tmer^(1/2)*Sqrt[w^2 - 1]*
     Sqrt[(u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel] + 
    1/2*(mh^2 - tmer - tmel) + (w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - 
    u*w*mh*tmer^(1/2)))*
Exp[u*mh]/((Exp[u*mh] - 1)*(Exp[w*tmer^(1/2)] + 
     1)*(Exp[u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2)] + 1)) // ExpandAll // Together

red1[mh_] = 
Reduce[{u > 1, w > 1, (u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 >= tmel}, u, Reals];

IDtest[mh_] := 
NIntegrate[Boole[red1[mh]]*ii[u, w, mh], {u, 1, \[Infinity]}, {w, 
1, \[Infinity]}]

IDtest[.4]
(*   0.0234479 + 1.68786*10^-25 I   *)

Plot[IDtest[mh], {mh, .4, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: It is nice code (+1), but we can avoid complex numbers by using a trick `Sqrt[Sqrt[((u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel)^2]]`.

Answer (score 4):

One can split the integration region up:

```
tmer=17/1000;tmel=44/1000;
IDtest[mh_] := Quiet[
 1/(8*Pi^3)*(
 NIntegrate[(mh*tmer^(1/2)*(tmer^(1/2)*Sqrt[w^2 - 1]*Sqrt[(u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel]+1/2*(mh^2-tmer-tmel)+(w*tmer^(1/2))^2-u*w*mh*tmer^(1/2)))* Exp[u*mh]/((Exp[u*mh] - 1)*(Exp[w*tmer^(1/2)]+1)*(Exp[u*mh-w*tmer^(1/2)]+1))//Expand//Together,
  {w,1,+\[Infinity]},{u,Max[1,(Sqrt[tmel]+Sqrt[tmer]w)/mh],+Infinity},MinRecursion->1]+
  NIntegrate[(mh*tmer^(1/2)*(tmer^(1/2)*Sqrt[w^2 - 1]*Sqrt[(u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel]+1/2*(mh^2-tmer-tmel)+(w*tmer^(1/2))^2-u*w*mh*tmer^(1/2)))* Exp[u*mh]/((Exp[u*mh] - 1)*(Exp[w*tmer^(1/2)]+1)*(Exp[u*mh-w*tmer^(1/2)]+1))//Expand//Together,
  {w,1,+Infinity},{u,1,Max[1,(-Sqrt[tmel]+Sqrt[tmer]w)/mh]},
  Method->{"GlobalAdaptive","SymbolicProcessing"->0,Method->"MultidimensionalRule"}]
  ),
  {NIntegrate::slwcon}];

Table[mh->IDtest[mh],{mh,0.4,2.,0.1}]//AbsoluteTiming

(*
{3.60748,
 {0.4 -> 0.0234479 + 8.80489*^-29*I,
  0.5 -> 0.0207372,
  0.6 -> 0.0185911,
  …
  2. -> 0.00734608}}
*)
```

Comment: Very original +1. Why not to use `UnitStep`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you. I was thinking to remove the singularities from the `Sqrt[]` the interior of the integration domain. Symbolic processing might do it for me if I used `UnitStep`, I suppose, but I didn’t try it. If not, then when an integration rule is applied to a subregion that contains a singularity, you usually (and should) get a large error estimate. It takes a great number of subdivisions to reduce the error. To avoid that was my aim.

Comment: Have a look at my code. I am using a trick  `Sqrt[Sqrt[((u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel)^2]]` to avoid complex numbers.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I just did, and +1 to you. :)

Comment: Thank you. I guess that we can reduce time with using `Compile`.

Answer (score 2):

**Supplement to @AlexTrounev** interesting answer:

The unknown intergal `Integrate[f[...],...]`

can be written as sum of two parts `Integrate[UnitStep[] f[...],...]+Integrate[(1-UnitStep[] )f[...],...]==IDtest[mh]+dIDtest[mh]`!

```
    IDtest[mh_] := 
 1/(8*Pi^3)*
  NIntegrate[
   UnitStep[(u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel] (mh*
       tmer^(1/2)*(tmer^(1/2)*Sqrt[w^2 - 1]*
          Sqrt[Sqrt[((u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel)^2]] + 
         1/2*(mh^2 - tmer - tmel) + (w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - 
         u*w*mh*tmer^(1/2)))*
     Exp[u*mh]/((Exp[u*mh] - 1)*(Exp[w*tmer^(1/2)] + 
            1)*(Exp[u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2)] + 1))/x^2/y^2 /. {u -> 1/x, 
     w -> 1/y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 5]

dIDtest[mh_] := 
     1/(8*Pi^3)*
      NIntegrate[
       (1-UnitStep[(u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel]) (mh*
           tmer^(1/2)*(tmer^(1/2)*Sqrt[w^2 - 1]*
              Sqrt[Sqrt[((u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - tmel)^2]] + 
             1/2*(mh^2 - tmer - tmel) + (w*tmer^(1/2))^2 - 
             u*w*mh*tmer^(1/2)))*
         Exp[u*mh]/((Exp[u*mh] - 1)*(Exp[w*tmer^(1/2)] + 
                1)*(Exp[u*mh - w*tmer^(1/2)] + 1))/x^2/y^2 /. {u -> 1/x, 
         w -> 1/y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
       Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}, 
       PrecisionGoal -> 5]
```

The part `dIDtest` is a small correction  for small values `mh`

```
Table[{mh, IDtest[mh] + dIDtest[mh], IDtest[mh] }, {mh,  .4, 2., .2}]
(*{{0.4, 0.023492, 0.0234493}, 
{0.6, 0.0186633, 0.0185858},
{0.8,0.0153775, 0.0153775}, 
{1., 0.013071, 0.013071}, 
{1.2, 0.0113453,0.0113453}, 
{1.4, 0.0100059, 0.0100059}, 
{1.6, 0.00893805,0.00893805}, 
{1.8, 0.00807154, 0.00807154}, 
{2., 0.00734856,0.00734856}}*)
```